# Examples of library-provided std::hash specializations that produce different values over different executions of a program

Tags: c++, hash

The [page about `std::hash` over on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) states the following since C++14:

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the
>   same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted
>   hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks.

And indeed, the C++ Standard mentions this requirement in [[hash.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/hash.requirements), specifically for the expression `h(k)` in the table *Hash requirements*:

> The value returned shall depend only on the argument k for the
>   duration of the program. [ Note: Thus all evaluations of the
>   expression h(k) with the same value for k yield the same result for a
>   given execution of the program. — end note ] [ Note: For two different
>   values t1 and t2, the probability that h(t1) and h(t2) compare equal
>   should be very small, approaching 1.0 /
>   numeric_­limits​::​max(). — end note ]

It seems to me that this requirement is introduced to cater to user-provided specializations, allowing salted hashes. If I understood everything correctly, it does also allow a library-provided specialization of `std::hash` to produce different results over different executions of a program.

**Question:** Is there any implementation of the C++14 standard that provides one or more specializations for `std::hash` that do not consistently produce the same result in different executions of a program when given the exact same value as input on each execution?

Comment: Of course it would be bad practice. Ignoring the standard just risks you being locked into a particular version of a particular implementation should the implementation change on something you ***knew*** you should ***not*** rely on. `std::hash` is quite is clearly for internal runtime hashing. If you want to rely on a consistent hash, pick something that _does_ suit your needs: MD5, Sum Of Sums, SHA, or whatever...

Comment: @CraigYoung : Better long-term replacements for `std::hash` would be CRC32 or Adler32.  (Like `std::hash` those are not cryptographic hashes.)

Comment: Does that mean you would ever consider it good practice to ignore the standard for any given topic?  I want to upvote for the research; but the question is so distinctly not helpful as it suggests that there are times the answer is yes.

Comment: I have removed the last sentence as it distracted from the main question and suggested that not adhering to the standard could be considered good practice in some cases.
I am just curious if there is any standard library implementation that provides some kind of salted hashes out of the box or if the quoted requirement is only aimed at user-provided specializations.

Comment: I think it *can* be good practise to ignore the standard in certain cases.  For example, I regularly rely on the fact that `int` can hold at least 32-bit integers, although the standard only guarantees 16-bit.  I am aware that this potentially limits my portability, but it seems an acceptable trade-off.  Similarly, I sometimes rely on the fact that using `memset` to set a pointer to all-bits-zero will leave it as a null pointer.  This is not guaranteed either.

Comment: @MartinBonner What information do you have to go on that CRC or Adler would suit OP's purposes? If OP want a hash signature of files MD5 is already widely used. (ftr Sum Of Sums is not cryptographic either. I picked 3 instead of trying to list every known hash. OP would have to assess what best suits the requirements.)

Comment: As for your reliance on 32-bit integers, I would say it's not really the same thing. Your compilers are unlikely to reduce what they already support. Whereas a compiler _adding_ changing the salt of `std::hash` on each run would more likely be considered "adding functionality". **Anecdote**: SQL Server 6.5 used to return GROUP BY data sorted by the same key as a side effect of it's particular implementation. Developers who had _incorrectly_ relied on that struggled to upgrade when newer versions used a faster GROUP BY that didn't incidentally sort.